# Just upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 but cannot find localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-16.04

I just upgrade my Ubuntu 15.10 to Ubuntu 16.04
Now, the problem is that eventhough there is all Php7, mysql and apache in the system, the page `localhost/phpmyadmin` cannot be opened.

This is the error message displayed.
[image: This is the error message displayed]

Mysql, apache and phpmyadmin are all installed. Yet, the problem does not seem to stop. I know that i can delete the current php7 and install php5, but i would like to make this work in php7 itself. (If that's the problem)

Comment: Is anything in nginx error.log?

Comment: Oh, sorry, you use Apache server so enter in terminal `gedit /var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: Was there anything in the upgrade notes about Apache or MySQL? Is the Apache server actually running? Do other pages on that machine (from your web root, perhaps) open correctly?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch Nope there were no notes. And Yes, the Apache server is running. And Nope other pages are not running

Comment: Then I definitely suspect something is wrong with your Apache installation. If it's not properly serving pages, it should log something; if it's not then there's something else broken. It's possible the log location is different from what Ján Kyselica suggested, though. This might help you find the access log http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38978/where-are-apache-file-access-logs-stored -- the error log is probably in the same folder. Also, check the access log and see if it's logging anything during your access attempts.

Comment: @JánKyselica  `[Sun Apr 24 11:05:19.211460 2016]  [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11763] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations  

[Sun Apr 24 16:32:29.734201 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11763] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down  
[Mon Apr 25 17:17:30.328359 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1063] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down`
These are the codes in the error.log file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long time ago I had the same issue. The issue was fixed by reinstalling the missing packages like `apache`, `mysql`, `phpMyAdmin` and `other missing PHP packages`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
sudo apt install php7.0-mbstring php-gettext
```

Answer (score 1):

install libapache2-mod-php, this works for me

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue because I have removed by mistake all the php-* packages from my installation. So try to **reinstall packages** such as:

```
// Install missing packages for apache2
sudo apt-get install apache2

// Install phpmyadmin missing packages
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin

// Install common php packages
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0-fpm php7.0-cli php7.0-common \
                     php7.0-json php7.0-opcache php7.0-mysql \
                     php7.0-phpdbg php7.0-mbstring php7.0-gd \ 
                     php7.0-imap php7.0-ldap php7.0-pgsql \ 
                     php7.0-pspell php7.0-recode php7.0-snmp \ 
                     php7.0-tidy php7.0-dev php7.0-intl \ 
                     php7.0-gd php7.0-curl php7.0-zip php7.0-xml
```

Notice that you probably don't need all these php-* packages but this depends on you current needs.

Answer (score 1):

I installed php-mbstring php-gettext

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php-gettext
```

then I restarted apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar issue soon after upgrading to ubuntu 16.10. Then nothing was working, so i unistalled everything including `php, apache, phpmyadmin` and installed again. This have fixed the issue.